# Drawing edges of a pentagonal pyramid in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw lines between v_2,...,v_6 and from v_1 to all the other points (a pyramid). This is how far I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics, tikz, tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape]
  \tikzstyle{LabelStyle}=[fill=white,sloped]
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{$v_2$}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=0]{$v_3$}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=1.5]{$v_4$}
  \Vertex[x=1.5,y=2.5]{$v_5$}
  \Vertex[x=-1,y=1.5]{$v_6$}
  \Vertex[x=1.5,y=4.5]{$v_1$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following graph:

[image: Graph]
Which is almost okay, but I can't seem to add edges. I tried to add `\Edge[]($v_1$)($v_2$)` to the code but that gives me the error 'paragraph ended before parse was completed'. Apparently the problem has something to do with the `$v_i$` because the code runs if I delete the dollar signs.

Comment: You should have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78113/34551 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95801/34551 probably contains your solution.

Comment: @Clément The second link helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Based on the posts in comment, [How to reuse vertex names using the tkz-berge graph drawing package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78112) and [Referencing a Vertex that has Math Typesetting inside it to make an Edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95800/))

You should separate the labels from the name of the nodes.
A minimal patch :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics, tikz, tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape]
  \tikzstyle{LabelStyle}=[fill=white,sloped]
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0,L=$v_2$]{v2}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=0,L=$v_3$]{v3}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=1.5,L=$v_4$]{v4}
  \Vertex[x=1.5,y=2.5,L=$v_5$]{v5}
  \Vertex[x=-1,y=1.5,L=$v_6$]{v6}
  \Vertex[x=1.5,y=4.5,L=$v_1$]{v1}
  \Edge[](v1)(v2)
  \Edge[](v4)(v5)
  %etc.
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is not using labels when defining the positions of the vertex, and instead assigning all of them later, with `\AssignVertexLabel`. Note however that this macro expects the nodes numbered from 0, not from 1 (but you can assign them labels from `$_1$`).

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics, tikz, tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape]
  \tikzstyle{LabelStyle}=[fill=white,sloped]
  \SetVertexNoLabel
  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{v1}
  \Vertex[x=3,y=0]{v2}
  \Vertex[x=4,y=1.5]{v3}
  \Vertex[x=1.5,y=2.5]{v4}
  \Vertex[x=-1,y=1.5]{v5}
  \Vertex[x=1.5,y=4.5]{v0}
  \AssignVertexLabel{v}{$v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$,$v_4$,$v_5$,$v_6$}
  \Edges(v5,v4,v0);\Edges(v4,v3)
  \SetUpEdge[color=white,style={double=black,double distance=2pt}]
  \Edges(v0,v3,v2,v1,v5,v0)
  \Edges(v1,v0,v2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image: Result]